# How to import packages/modules into spyder?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, numpy, windows-8.1, spyder

I just installed python in my MacOS using the Anaconda distribution. My problem is although the packages (eg. matplotlib, numpy, scipy) came included with the installation, I have to import them to spyder every time which is tedious and it's also tiring that that I have to remind spyder of their functionalities.

For eg, in Windows, I only needed to type in the console:
**x=array([...,...,...])**

but in my mac it would have to be:
**import numpy as py**
and then type into the console:
**x=py.array([...,...,...])**

I do notice that in that the spyder-python console (Windows version), there is a text saying,

**Imported NumPy 1.8.1, SciPy 0.13.3, Matplotlib 1.3.1 + guidata 1.6.1, guiqwt 2.3.2

Type "scientific" for more details.**

That is probably the reason why I don't have to import anything in Windows because Spyder already did it.
How do I do the same for Mac?

Thank you

Comment: In Spyder look at the dialog tab *Tools->Preferences->IPython Console*. There you have the option *Automatically load Pylab and Numpy Modules*.

Comment: Thanks you gave me a place to start. I got it :)